What animated movie is this? [had happy meal toy, picture in post]
What movie is this robot from? It was an animated movie that had toys in McDonald's Happy Meals in the last 8 years. The movie had great animation, something that was like magic or techno-sorcery, and had fighting robots. The robot from the picture is like the main robot, it didn't speak, but the boy in the story had a bond with it. Also the robots fought in an arena of sorts, but I can't remember if they had to or if it was for sport.
Please help, this is killing me. 


It's Zog from Astro Boy (2009).

Set in futuristic Metro City, Astro Boy is about a young robot with incredible powers created by a brilliant scientist in the image of the son he has lost. Unable to fulfill the grieving man's expectations, our hero embarks on a journey in search of acceptance, experiencing betrayal and a netherworld of robot gladiators, before he returns to save Metro City and reconcile with the father who had rejected him.


Slight similarity to Baymax, if you ask me... Hmm. Anyway, here's the trailer:



